# Value Error calling for more than 2 values

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm getting this value error

```
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack)
```

and I don't know what it means.

Here is my code:

```
contact_map = {'Dennis Jones': ('989-123-4567', 'Dennis@gmail.com'), 'Susan': ('517-345-1234', 'susan_smith@anr.msu.edu'), 'Miller, Matthew': ('616-765-4321', 'matt@yahoo.com')}
FORM = "{:<s};{:<d};{:<s}"

out_file = input("Enter a name for the output file: ")
output_file= open(out_file, "w")

for name, phone, email in contact_map.items():
    output_file.write(FORM.format(name, phone, email))

output_file.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

There must be two present when invoking `dict.items()` key and value. After that you need to unpack the value part in-order to get phone and email.

```
for name, value in contact_map.items():
    phone = value[0]
    email = value[1]
    output_file.write(FORM.format(name, phone, email))
```

Answer (score 4):

You're getting the error because you're attempting to unpack a tuple of `len==3` (`name, phone, email`) but the `items()` returns `(key, value)`, where `value` in this case is a tup of length 2.

You can unpack this in one line like:

```
for name, (phone, email) in contact_map.items():
```

Answer (score 2):

`dict.items()` returns a tuple with a key and a value. The first element of `dict.items()` would be:

```
('Dennis Jones', ('989-123-4567', 'Dennis@gmail.com'))
```

The interpreter expects you to unpack this tuple into two values (one for `'Dennis Jones'`, the other for `('989-123-4567', 'Dennis@gmail.com')`). In order to loop through the three items (name, phone and email), you can unpack the inner tuple by surrounding `phone, email` in parenthesis:

```
for name, (phone, email) in contact_map.items():
    output_file.write(FORM.format(name, phone, email))
```